# Save tweets of specific hashtag to JSON file

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am new to programming and am applying python to a project where I need to analyze a specific Twitter hashtag. I have successfully displayed the tweets of the specific hashtag but I am not able to save them to a JSON file.

I would appreciate any help with this

below my code:

```
#Import necessary libaries to access Twitter
import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd
import tweepy as OAuthHandler
# Access keys and tokens to Twitter 
consumer_key=''
consumer_secret=''
access_token=''
access_token_secret=''
#Access Twitter
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
#this to allow us to generate multiple requests and skip the waiting time
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
 #Define the query of our search
#query='#Astrazeneca'
query=input('print selected hashtag starting with #: ')
tweets=tw.Cursor(api.search,q=query,lang='en').items(50)
#for tweet in tweets:
    #print(tweet.text)
# make the tweets in a list
all_tweets=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
all_tweets[0:5]
```

```
# Save tweets to JSON file 
import json
for tweet in all_tweets:
    with open('tweetsfile._json','w',encoding='utf8') as file:
        json.dump(tweet._json, file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)
```

The error I receive:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a82813c9d641> in <module>
      3 for tweet in all_tweets:
      4     with open('tweet.text_json','w',encoding='utf8') as file:
----> 5         json.dump(tweet._json, file,sort_keys = True,indent = 4)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_json'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your list `all_tweets` you are calling `tweet.text` which returns a `string`. A `string` has no attribute `_json`, however your `tweet` object (before calling `.text` does.

Change that to include the object `tweet` instead which should open the ability to call `tweet._json` in your loop.

```
all_tweets=[tweet for tweet in tweets]
```